# Text Input Layout Doesn't Get Immediately Updated After Disabling Hardware Acceleration

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-manifest, android-textinputlayout

I was experimenting with attributes in manifest file and their effects on app. I put some large bitmaps to app and to avoid Out Of memory error I added the following lines to manifest file.

```
  android:hardwareAccelerated="false" 
    android:largeHeap="true"
```

Now after adding this, I did not get any out of memory error but my `TextInputLayout` which has a child element `TextInputEditText`(same result with EditText)` does not get updated until the keyboard is hidden. Actually it probably gets updated but I can't see the update in the screen so it is empty until I hide the keyboard. This problem doesn't happen with normal edit texts. Removing

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

solves this problem but then `Out Of Memory` error returns. I know using these two flags isn't the right approach to solve the `Out Of Memory` error but this behavior seems so strange and I couldn't find any info about it elsewhere. Is this a known bug and how can it be solved?

Small note: Removing textinput layouts and converting them to EditTexts is a "hack" and not a fix to this bug so please don't suggest that